# Mounted SFTP to AWS Linux - Not able to read

Tags: linux, mount, sftp

I mounted a SFTP server to my linux AWS server with the following steps. 
I can see the SFTP server files in my folder. But I am not able to read or view

I followed the steps in this link http://www.tecmint.com/sshfs-mount-remote-linux-filesystem-directory-using-ssh/

1. yum install sshfs
2. mkdir /mnt/tecmint
3. sshfs tecmint@x.x.x.x:/home/tecmint/ /mnt/tecmint
4. cd /mnt/tecmint
5. ls //Now I can see the files from SFTP server.

df -hT //I can see the mount, but usage is 0%

But I am not able to view

> ```
> more EDI832.dat
> EDI832.dat: No such file or directory
> ```

If I try to copy, i got this error 
cp EDI832.dat /home/joseph/tmp
cp: cannot open ‘EDI832.dat’ for reading: No such file or directory

The new local unix folder access is changed to 'users'. that might be the reason for no find found. but i am not able to change the permission.